# How to get form-field values via Camunda Rest-Api

Tags: rest, bpmn, camunda

Is there any way to explicitly get the values of a user tasks form field?
I have a form field with three enum values.

[image]

When I do the REST call `/task/{id}/form-variables` I get following output:

```
{
"pruefungOk": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": null,
        "valueInfo": {}
    }
}
```

But what i would like to have is something like:

```
{
"pruefungOk": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": null,
        "valueInfo": {},
        "availableValues": ["ok", "notOk", "helloTest"] <-- Array of the values from first picture
    }
}
```

Is that somehow possible without doing workaround and dirty code? And why isnt there a REST Call for that?

Comment: Have anyone solved that issue? Personally, we use additional variable of our custom type to solve the problem.

Comment: If there is enum type of variable -> creste new object and fill this property availableValues out with enum values from form variable...

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late, but maybe you will use it some other time or it will be help for some other. What I did is the following:

```
TaskFormData taskFormData = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine().getFormService().getTaskFormData(taskId);
```

And after that to get the values:

```
taskFormData.getFormFields()
            .forEach(formField -> {
                if (formField.getType() instanceof EnumFormType) {
                    ((EnumFormType) (formField.getType())).getValues().forEach((key, value) -> {
                        System.out.println("This is the key:" + key);
                        System.out.println("This is the value:" + value);
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: But when we need to pass this code and how can we get variables in swagger?

Comment: @Митяй I am not sure I follow what you mean with `we need to pass this code` and for the swagger question I don't have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at https://forum.camunda.org/t/how-to-get-form-field-properties-using-rest-api/5981. Looks like the same use case.

Comment: Not a fan of the approach described there because it requires writing static values to the variables of every instances and fills up the DB unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Does https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.13/reference/rest/task/get-rendered-form/
help? I know it is not perfect, but should contain the options.

To extract static information from the bpmn file you can also always resort to
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.13/reference/rest/process-definition/get-xml/
and then apply e.g. jQuery to the bpmn20Xml in the response.